# By decreasing the windows size my header does this?

Tags: html, css, dom

I was trying to create a website which has nav bar. But while coding navbar and testing i was facing issue and i observed that it was not responsive.so whenever i try to load the website in lower resolution nav bar was getting displaced from its original position to adjacent position vertically. Which was awkward as it seems in 1st image.

After Decreasing the window size navbar shift to below the image
[image]

Normal large window size
[image]

Here is the code. i have attached HTMl and CSS.

reference Video link -> https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TTbYFzAz-Lg

I have tried to make responsive navbar.. but i'm not getting the behaviour of navbar when the window size deceases.

HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>
            Responsive Navigation Bar
        </title>
        <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width initial-scale=1">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="header">
            <div id="logo">
                <img src="Redbull-logo.png">
            </div>
            <ul id="navbar">
                <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Service</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Product</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

CSS

```
*{
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
}

body{
    background: skyblue;
}

#header{
    width: 100%;
    height: 80px;
    background: #333;
    box-shadow: 0px 3px 4px gray;
}

#navbar{
    width: 1000px;
    height: 80px;
    float: right;
}

#navbar > li{
    width: 198px;
    list-style: none;
    float: left;
    border-right: 1px solid gray;
    border-left: 1px solid gray;
}

li > a{
    display: block;
    color: white;
    line-height: 80px;
    text-align: center;
    font-family: cursive;
    font-size: 20px;
    text-decoration: none;
} 

li > a:hover,
li > a:focus{
    background-color: skyblue;
    color: #333;
}

#logo{
    width: 200px;
    float: left;
    height: 80px;
    padding-left: 40px; 
}
```

Comment: Why don't you post some code?

Comment: Some links to help you ask better questions: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask, [MCVE]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically what is happening is when you decrease the size of the screen there isn't enough room in the nav bar for all your links and also your image so it pushes it onto two lines, I would look into media queries so at certain widths things change like the size of your image and the size of your nav links.

An example of how this would work

```
@media (max-width: 1080px){
   navbar-links{
     font-size: 0.8em;
     padding: 0px 5px;
   }

   navbar-image{
     width: 500px;
   }
```

Comment: Please do not answer off topic questions that do not provide any code and are unclear as to what the problem is (and too broad). Doing so dilutes the usefulness of SO. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer

Comment: i think i got my answer. but when size decreases the links pushes into 2nd lines and further decreases make links disappear but why image stays the same??

Comment: @Karsh Soni Like I said you have to set media queries so at certain widths your images and nav links scale, so when your navbar splits into two set a media query and make your image smaller. I would consider taking a basic CSS class because this would definitely be covered.

Comment: thanks, its working,